# How to update all the NuGet packages in a solution starting with a particular name?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget

For example, I am looking for a command like this which will update only packages that start with the name `PackagePrefix`:

```
Update-Package "PackagePrefix.*"
```

I tried the script provided in the comments section of [this blog](https://blog.nuget.org/20121231/a-quick-tutorial-on-update-package-command.html), but it is throwing the following error:

```
Get-Package | Where Id -like "Contoso.*" | Sort-Object -Property Id -Unique | foreach { Update-Package $_.Id }
```

> ```
> Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "Id" value of type "System.String" to type
> "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
> At line:1 char:20
> + Get-Package | Where <<<<  Id -like "Contoso.*" | Sort-Object -Property Id -Unique | foreach { Update-Package $_.Id }
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
> ```

Comment: That script works fine for me...

Comment: I have Powershell 2.0 and NuGet 3.0. Could be an issue because of my Powershell version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling around a little bit, I figured that I am using a very old version of Powershell (v2.0) and based on [the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx) the following script works now. I replaced `Where` with `Where-Object`:

```
Get-Package | Where-Object {$_.Id -like "Contoso.*"} | Sort-Object -Property Id -Unique | foreach { Update-Package $_.Id }
```